# Condensing multiple email alerts into just 1 email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to coding so my knowledge is not that great, but I was able to successfully create a script for an email alert based on a Google Sheet. The script will send an email alert to myself based on a date in a specific cell. This is also done across multiple tabs in the sheet. However, right now it sends an email per row. I'm looking to try condense it so it only sends 1 email per tab encompassing all the rows in that specific tab. Is there a way to have this done?

I have not been able to try anything to make this work, but sharing the current code below as reference.

```
function feedbackAlert() {
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var todayDay = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var only = [
    'Sheet 1',
    'Sheet 2',
    'Sheet 3'
    ];
  only.forEach(function(name){
    var s = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var startRow = 14;
    var numRows = 100;
    var dataset = s.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 999);
    var value = dataset.getValues();
    var productName = s.getRange("C5").getValue();
      for (var u = 0; u < value.length; ++u) {
        var row = value[u];
        var dueDateFormat = Utilities.formatDate(
          new Date(row[5]),
          'ET',
          'MM/dd/yyyy'
        );
        var subject = '';
        var message =
          ' Feedback is Due - ' + productName +
          '\n' +
          ' Name: ' +
          row[1] +
          '\n' +
          ' Formula #: ' +
          row[2] +
          '\n' +
          ' Feedback Due Date: ' +
          dueDateFormat;
        var dueDateMonth = new Date(row[5]).getMonth() + 1;
        var dueDateDay = new Date(row[5]).getDate();
        var dueDateYear = new Date(row[5]).getFullYear();
        if (
          dueDateMonth === todayMonth &&
          dueDateDay === todayDay &&
          dueDateYear === todayYear
        ) {
          var subject =
            'NPD Feedback is Due: ' + productName;
          MailApp.sendEmail('email', subject, message);
          Logger.log('NPD Feedback Alert!');
        }
      }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function puts all of the all messages for each product into a different email

```
function feedbackAlert() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ['Sheet 1', 'Sheet 2', 'Sheet 3'];
  const sr = 14;
  const numRows = 100;
  shts.forEach(name => {
    var arr = [];
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, numRows, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var pn = sh.getRange("C5").getValue();
    vs.forEach((r, u) => {
      let ddt = new Date(r[5]);
      let ddtv = new Date(ddt.getFullYear(), ddt.getMonth(), ddt.getDate()).valueOf()
      let ddtF = Utilities.formatDate(ddt, 'ET', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
      let message = `Feeback is due: ${pn} Name: ${r[1]} Formula #: ${r[2]} Feedback due date: ${ddtF}`
      if (ddtv == dtv) {
        arr.push(message);
      }
    });
    if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
      MailApp.sendEmail('Your email', `Feedback is Due for ${pn}` , arr.join("\n"))
    }
  });
}
```

It requires you to add your email address

Comment: Can you share some data in  a table? Just to save you the trouble I don't follow links to spreadsheets.

Comment: Sorry I realized my mistake (in my spreadsheet - I was trying to test it without it even having today's date. Oops) But now I'm getting an error from Apps Script "Type Error: arr.push is not a function"

Comment: Try it again.  For some reason it did not get my last change

Comment: Oh it's working! I'm wondering however, if there's a way to separate the emails based on tab? To give a bit of perspective, each tab is a different product, and I'd like for the subject to include said product names

Comment: Yes that's possible or we can just put the prducts in different sections of one email

Comment: I guess whichever makes it easier. As the projects come and go, the # of included sheet that run this email alert function would change. So I'm not 100% sure which makes the most sense.

Comment: Oh you want the subject to contain prod name

Comment: I can go either way.  I'll go the way you suggest at first.  It shouldn't take too long.

Comment: It's ready for you to take a look at

Comment: It works beautifully! Thank you so so much for all your help!!